# How to detect word clicked within the iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a iframe on my web page. is there a way or JS library I can use to know which word user click within the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

In long, yes.

If the iFrame is loaded on the same sub-domain and domain name as the page that contains the iFrame (`www.example.com`), you can interact with it without doing anything special.

If your iFrame is loaded on the same domain, but a different sub-domain (`sub1.example.com`, `sub2.example.com`), put this line of javascript at the top of your javascript file, in both the iFrame page and the page that contains it:

```
document.domain = 'example.com';
```

This will make the iFrame "think" that it is ok to communicate through javascript.

If the iFrame is on an entirely different domain, there is nothing you can do.